# Table cell is not respecting CSS width value

Tags: html, css, html-table, pre

I was just going through [this Github doc](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/understanding-github-actions#understanding-the-workflow-file) when I noticed the table was hard to read and started poking around the CSS to make it more eye appealing.

However, I realised that the `td` elements in the table were not respecting any `width` properties that I set. To reproduce the issue, I created [this codepen](https://codepen.io/AnirudhMS/pen/YzvVKZW). The styles in the codepen are from the Github docs.

The codepen has 2 tables: one whose contents contain a `pre` and a `code` tag and another which contains plain text. I have added an additional style in my codepen for all `td` elements: `width: 50%`. The first table does not respect this style while the second one does. Can anyone tell me why? Also, is there any explanation to why all the cells in the first table are affected and do not respect the width when only one cell has the `pre` and `code` tags?

Edit: Here's a code sample:

```css
:root {
  --color-border-muted: #21262d;
  --color-canvas-default: #0d1117;
  --color-fg-default: #c9d1d9;
  --color-canvas-subtle: #161b22;
  --color-border-default: #30363d;
}

body {
  /* Styles from Githun docs */
  color-scheme: dark;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

table {
  /* Styles from Githun docs */
  display: table;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 90%;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 1.5;
  table-layout: auto;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  color: var(--color-fg-default);
}

table tr {
  /* Styles from Githun docs */
  background-color: var(--color-canvas-default);
  border-top: 1px solid var(--color-border-muted);
}

td {
  /* STYLE THAT MARKS THAT CELL WIDTH SHOULD ONLY BE 50% */
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid var(--color-border-muted);
  padding: 0.5rem;
}

pre {
  /* Styles from Githun docs */
  padding: 16px;
  overflow: auto;
  line-height: 1.45;
  background-color: var(--color-canvas-subtle);
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin-top: .5rem;
border: 1px solid var(--color-border-default);
  word-wrap: normal;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Hello Margarita tula pera kola papaya. sdkjcnskdcn kjsdnckcnskdjnc k ckjdc ksdc kdjc kd ckd cksdj cjkd c sdk cskdjc kjd ckdj ckdjsc ksdjc kdjc dksc kdj c</td>
      <td>World</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hello</td>
      <td>World</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hello</td>
      <td>World</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hello</td>
      <td>World</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br />
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Hello Margarita tula pera kola papaya. sdkjcnskdcn kjsdnckcnskdjnc k ckjdc ksdc kdjc kd ckd cksdj cjkd c sdk cskdjc kjd ckdj ckdjsc ksdjc kdjc dksc kdj c</td>
      <td>World</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><pre><code class="hljs language-yaml"><span class="hljs-attr">run-name:</span> <span class="hljs-string">${{</span> <span class="hljs-string">github.actor</span> <span class="hljs-string">}}</span> <span class="hljs-string">is</span> <span class="hljs-string">learning</span> <span class="hljs-string">GitHub</span> <span class="hljs-string">Actions</span> <span class="hljs-string">Actions</span> <span class="hljs-string">Actions</span> <span class="hljs-string">Actions</span> <span class="hljs-string">Actions</span> <span class="hljs-string">Actions</span></code></pre></td>
      <td>World</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hello</td>
      <td>World</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hello</td>
      <td>World</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

TLDR: In [the codepen](https://codepen.io/AnirudhMS/pen/YzvVKZW) the table with `pre` and `code` tags in cells does not respect the `width: 50%` style set on cell elements (`td`). Why?

Comment: _"Why?"_ - because: `table-layout: auto` // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout

Comment: @CBroe I did think of this earlier and removed the style. However, the result did not change. But what I failed to consider earlier was that the default browser value for the `table-layout` property is still `auto`. So, I have to explicitly mark it as `fixed` or it is always going to stay `auto`.

Comment: The `pre`-tag does not wrap text by default. Setting `white-space: pre-wrap` on the `pre`-tag makes the text wrap and "fixes" the table layout.

Answer (score 0):

Credits: [@CBroe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1427878/cbroe)

In the above CSS, there is one specific style that was responsible for the width not being respected:

```
table {
  .
  .
  .
  table-layout: auto;
  .
  .
}
```

As mentioned in the [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout), a value of `auto` to `table-layout` results as follows:

> By default, most browsers use an automatic table layout algorithm. The widths of the table and its cells are adjusted to fit the content.

This means that in `auto`, the content decides the layout. As mentioned in [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_tab_table-layout.php):

> Browsers use an automatic table layout algorithm. The column width is set by the widest unbreakable content in the cells. The content will dictate the layout

So, you can replace it with `table-layout:fixed` to set your own width.

Note: Simply removing the style `table-layout: auto` will not do since the browser uses it as the default style. A value of `fixed` needs to be explicitly passed.